# Can we say "He began to talk 30 minutes ago and never stopped" in stead of "have not stopped"

Tags: word-usage

> *He began to talk 30 minutes ago and* **never stopped**

I have known that adverb "never" is usually used in present tense with meaning that the action hasn't ever happened and will never happened, but does it have meaning " the action has not happened but may happen"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence

> He began to talk 30 minutes ago and never stopped.

only refers to the time in the past up to now, that the speaker has been talking continuously. He may or may not stop in the future, that is left unsaid.

It is equivalent to

> He began to talk 30 minutes ago and has not stopped.

A popular phrase with the same construction is

> She moved to the West Coast and *hasn't looked back*.

meaning she's never had second thoughts about moving to the West Coast.